# formatting sql server PRINT messages?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following Print statement which print some details but it is not tabbed properly and looks awful. is there any way i could print them in tabbed format so they all meet at the same place in the end of the line.

```
Print'ByLineID: '+ Convert (varchar,@bylineID,1 )+' , '+ Convert(varchar,@Count,1)+ ' matching records found, '+ Convert(varchar,@@rowcount,1)+' updated.'
```

End result:

```
ByLineID: 119952    , 168 matching records found, 0 updated.
ByLineID: 93979 , 56 matching records found, 0 updated.
ByLineID: 266021    , 45 matching records found, 0 updated.
ByLineID: 105976    , 44 matching records found, 0 updated.
ByLineID: 97525 , 40 matching records found, 0 updated.
ByLineID: 94138 , 39 matching records found, 0 updated.
ByLineID: 88967 , 37 matching records found, 0 updated.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Print
      'ByLineID: '+ 
      Convert (varchar,@bylineID,1 ) + char(9) + ' , ' +
      Convert(varchar,@Count,1)  + char(9) +
      ' matching records found, ' +
      Convert(varchar,@@rowcount,1) + char(9) +' updated.'
```

Add some tab characters?

Answer (score 0):

First, CONVERT VARCHAR without length is bad idea, you should try `Convert (varchar(10), @bylineID)`.

Also, if those info are important for you, you may consider create a log table, or at least temp log table to store those information, and select from log table to get better output.

```
CREATE TABLE #logmsg
 ( id INT Identity (1,1)
 , ByLineID VARCHAR(10)
 , RecordMatch INT
 , RecordUpdted INT
 , CreateDate DateTime DEFAULT(GETDATE()))
```